# How to change app_name into android manifest in runtime?

Tags: java, android

I have an app with "X"'s name, but I want that the user change this name when it wants, and then the app show in the launcher the new name until the user wants change it.

For example: (string.xml)

```
<string name="app_name">First Name</string>
```

and then when user change this string into app...
finally

```
<string name="app_name">New Name</string>
```

Comment: Android manifest can't be modified at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, the user does not have access directly or indirectly to the manifest while the app is live. Think about it, if they did have permission to change the manifest, they could make all kinds of changes to your application.

Comment: Yes, really you have reason, but i want know if I could the change name once that the app was installed. Thanks for your answer!!